# How do i protect my network from somebody trying to limit internet connection of other devices

Tags: networking, internet

Hello in my household everyone is using [NetCut](https://arcai.com/netcut/) to limit/cut internet connection. And I would like this nonsense to stop. The netcut offers protection but not all can devices have them so i cannot just install it on every devices.

I have access over the router (they dont know the admin password). Can i do something there that would stop netcut or other similar attacks since, they will just find another one if that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

NetCut folks also create NetCut defender for blocking it in LAN (https://arcai.com/netcut-defender/). You can also configure a static ARP settings for your router by assigning a stic IP address and MAC address mapping.

Comment: Yes the defender is alright for the PCs, but they are also cutting the TVs and other smart appliances, and i do not want to buy another router to isolate them. Can i know more about how this static ARP setting, how exactly does this protect (i guess i should ask how netcut works)

Comment: Visit this link: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/protect-your-computer-against-arp-poison-attack-netcut/&ved=2ahUKEwi17JHW_P7pAhVkzTgGHeVhDQIQFjALegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw1bBT9WU5QUSRBGZj2aB8SK&cshid=1592230975265

Comment: NetCut does an ARP spoofing attack, so you you can assign a fixed or static TCP/IP settings on your router. Follow the link I shared.

Comment: I think you may have a broken link there sir, So by simply fixing the IP addresses. all the fixed ip will be protected vice versa

Comment: Please kindly Google about it...

Comment: I did shortly i posted my first comment. I kinda get how it works. Its the solution now that i am curious. Is static IP enough ?

Comment: You also need to create static map of IP address and mac address.

Comment: Isnt how static IP set up on the router is by assigning a mac address an IP, therefore when the mac address is connected it gets the IP you assigned. Is this what you mean or  a different thing completely